# NSDataDetector is returning wrong date for languages other than English

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdatadetector

So I am using `NSDataDetector` to get date from different languages. It returns correct date for English but for other language the returned dates are current date. Here are the codes.

```
NSString *dateEn = @"Added on Wednesday, February 4, 2015 5:58:18 PM";
NSString *dateStringRussian = @"Добавлено: суббота, 26 декабря 2015 г. в 0:16:57";
NSString *dateStringPortuguese = @"Adicionado: sábado, 26 de dezembro de 2015 11:39:53";

__block NSDate *dateFromDetector;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:nil];
[detector enumerateMatchesInString:dateStringPortuguese options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, [dateStringPortuguese length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    dateFromDetector = result.date;    
}];

NSLog(@"date is %@", dateFromDetector);
```

> output Portuguese: 2016-02-25 22:04:18.530 DateDetector[1681:56498] date is 2016-02-25 18:09:53 +0000
>
> output Russian: 2016-02-25 22:14:03.416 DateDetector[1725:60212] date is 2016-02-24 18:46:57 +0000
>
> output English: 2016-02-25 22:12:13.123 DateDetector[1712:59498] date is 2015-02-04 12:28:18 +0000

What is wrong here?

Comment: I ran your code and the portuguese one worked fine for me.  In the russian one the data detector only matched the time substring and not the full date which is why it has the month/day from the current date.

Comment: NSDataDetector uses current locale to determine the date format. You wont be able to get the date with texts in Russian locale.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne, Is there any workaround to offset this problem.

Comment: Have you managed to work around the problem? maybe change the current locale prior to using the NSDataDetector?

Comment: @MottiShneor As in this case I already knew about the locale, I used `NSDateFormatter` instead of `NSDataDetector`.

```
if ([onlyDateString containsString:@"Adicionado:"]) {
            [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"]];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"'Adicionado: 'EEEE, dd 'de' MM 'de' yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
            manualDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:onlyDateString];
        }
```